# Jquery selector through variables

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I achieve the following:

```
$('#someId, #anotherId').addClass('newKlass');
```

Using variables, without having to write a new line for each `.addClass` action. I do not want to have to do the following:

```
firstEl = $('#someId');
secondEl = $('#anotherId');

firstEl.addClass('newKlass');
secondEl.addClass('newKlass');
```

Comment: store the element in an array and loop through them applying the class?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "using variables" here.  You can store the result of any operation in a variable, and conduct any operation you like on that variable.  What's wrong with the code you've written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make an array!

```
var elms = ["#this","#that"];

  elms.forEach(function(elm){
    $(elm).addClass('blue');
  })
```

example: http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/OXZAjQ

Comment: Thanks, that works! Furthermore I'd like to ask you: let's say you've got a 'switch' statement, where both cases '#this' and '#that' lead to the same thing. If you had 30 cases leading to the same thing, what's the best way of abbreviating that? Is there a similair matter as the above? I normally write one bellow the other, where the last case leads to the desired function

Comment: @Alexander In a switch statement I would just set the array to the values you want to change then pass that array into the function that changes them all.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt clear enough: switch (ID) { case 'one': case 'two': case 'three': myFunction(); break; case 'four': myOtherFunction(); break; } ... How would you abbreviate cases one - three, which all lead to the same function?

Comment: @Alexander not sure how to use a switch statement but instead you could have a series of 'if else' statements. with each 'if' checking if the id is found in an array of ids.

Comment: Sure thing, you could loop through the values and compare them in if statements each time. Thought there'd be a simple way with the switch statement, thanks anyway